# Crystal Reports - keep together

Tags: crystal-reports

Hopefully this is simple enough that someone can help. I have a simple row oriented report.
The problem I have is the Keep together command is chosen on the detail lines, but sometimes the detail lines will go over to the next page. There are usually 4 or 5 detail lines before the next group starts.

If there are more detail lines than will fit on the page, what I want it to do is a page break and start over showing the group header #1 (simple report with one group) and then start printing the details again.

So, what would the necessary formula be to keep the detail lines together? Why doesn't keep together keep together?

Comment: To clarify, do you want to *duplicate* the group header and the detail lines that would fit on the new page, or simply to push the entire group onto the second page. Hopefully the second -- that's what **Keep Group Together** does.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you want to select Keep Together on the group, not the details section. (Group Expert -> select your group and hit 'Options' -> 'Options' tab -> select 'Keep Group Together'). Selecting Keep Together on the Details section only causes that single row to not be split up (this is the default behavior, as far as I know).

I'm not 100% off the top of my head, but if there are more details than will fit on the page I think it will behave as you want; page breaking before the group starts and then continuing onto a second page.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you marked Keep Together on each Details section, which keeps each section from spliting not all of them.

Try checking it on Details general section in Section Expert.
Check this screen shot to see how:

[image: See here]

Answer (score 0):

In Crystal Reports 2008, you can elect to keep the header together, the details together, or the group footer together. You cannot elect to keep an entire group together, as far as i can tell, which is annoying

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's a Group Options property:
[image]